# Android library not supporting API level below 23

Tags: android

I am using [Pulsator4Droid](https://github.com/booncol/Pulsator4Droid), an android library for some animation. It's working fine in **API 23** but there is no support in API below 23 which crashes the app. Is there any way I can do this in Jelly Bean.

I want a version check before that animation, so if API is 23 Animation should be true, for below Animation false.

Comment: Are you really sure about this? Because in https://github.com/booncol/Pulsator4Droid, it says it support API 11+. Could be a bug in your code.

Comment: I will give you the crash report, as it crashes when i open the animation screen.